# extract value from xml using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i am receiving xml as a web response.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.example.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header/>
    <s:Body>
        <ProductIdResponse xmlns="http://example.org/">
            <Product>123</Product>
        <ProductIdResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am looking to extract value from xml using pure javascript and store it in variable. there are many example in stackoverflow but all are using DOM elements and jquery.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

have a look here: [XML Parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

you load the xml into an xml document, and then access the elements the same way you would on your page's document:

```js
    //initialize your xml for testing purposes
    txt='<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.example.org/soap/envelope/">';
    txt=txt+'<s:Header/>';
    txt=txt+'<s:Body>';
    txt=txt+'<ProductIdResponse xmlns="http://example.org/">';
    txt=txt+' <Product>123</Product>';
    txt=txt+'<ProductIdResponse>';
    txt=txt+'</s:Body>';
    txt=txt+'</s:Envelope>';
    
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
    } else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }
    var myProduct = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(myProduct);
```

**If you dont want to parse the xml into DOM, you can alternatively retrieve the data using RegEx matching**

check [Here](http://www.regexr.com/) for a good RegEx tester where you can practice regex.

```js
//initialize your xml for testing purposes
txt = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.example.org/soap/envelope/">';
txt = txt + '<s:Header/>';
txt = txt + '<s:Body>';
txt = txt + '<ProductIdResponse xmlns="http://example.org/">';
txt = txt + ' <Product>123</Product>';
txt = txt + ' <Product>Product 2</Product>';
txt = txt + '<ProductIdResponse>';
txt = txt + '</s:Body>';
txt = txt + '</s:Envelope>';

var myProducts = txt.match(/<Product>(.*?)<\/Product>/g);
myProducts.forEach(function(val, id) {
  myProducts[id] = myProducts[id].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
});
console.log(myProducts);
alert("2nd product is: " + myProducts[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am not looking for DOM :(

Comment: @user2202257 What do you expect to use if not DOM? What's wrong with using a DOM?

Comment: @user2202257 You are confusing HTML and jQuery with DOM. DOM is a standard for XML representation and manipulation of documents. So you **are** looking for DOM. You should use DOMParser as described in this answer.